# How to translate a Chinese name 泽 to Korean?

Tags: pronunciation, meaning

I would like to convert my name to korean, but I am having trouble with "泽" which can be 석 or 택. I would assume the name would be 하석민 or 하택민 after conversion. Does it matter which one I use?

Comment: According to [this document](http://scourt-file.cache.cdn.cloudn.co.kr/hanja/hanja.pdf), the character 泽 is not allowed for a person's name. I am not sure whether there is an exception for people from other countries. If you use 澤 instead, it has to be 택 by law.

Comment: It's your name, and both 석민 and 택민 sound totally normal in Korean.  It doesn't really "matter" because I can't imagine any Korean asking your original Chinese characters, looking them up in the dictionary, and telling you "No your name is wrong!" - so, go with whichever you prefer.

Comment: Maybe I should have asked first why you need to write your name in Korean. If it is not about the immigration stuff, you may also choose Korean characters based on how your name is actually pronounced. For example, 毛泽东 is called 마오쩌둥 (and also 모택동(毛澤東)) in South Korea.

Comment: @Klmo No, 澤 is definitely allowed for a person's name. It is a basic word in Korean education, and is always allowed to be a person's name. All hanja characters that appear in the document you provided is allowed to be used.

Comment: @짱멋진만찢남 You misunderstood what I had said. It has 澤 but not 泽. Korean children do not learn Simplified Chinese characters. Hanja consists mainly of Traditional Chinese characters. 澤 and 泽 have the same meaning, but it does not mean that both characters are allowed in South Korea.

Answer (score 1):

When we do *not* consider a pronunciation-based name as another option, I believe that 하택민 is the safest choice because of these three reasons:

1. Koreans do not use Simplified Chinese characters, such as 泽, so you should use Traditional Chinese characters or Hanja instead. 澤 used for a *personal name* has to be pronounced as 택 in South Korea. By law, there are no options to its sound.
2. 택민 does not sound strange at all. Some Koreans have it as their first name.
3. If you use 석민, public servants or other workers could make mistakes about your name when they use the "Korean character to Hanja" converter. For 석, the Hanja lists of Windows 10 and the word processor [한글](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%ED%95%9C/%EA%B8%80) have neither 澤 nor 泽. *It matters* if you do not want to waste time on this.

I have no idea why you wish to use a Korean name, but if you are going to live in South Korea, you should *conform to Korean customs and obey the law*.